# Simple Rust Todo List with auto incrementing ID

Tags: rust, to-do-list

I have recently started learning Rust and thought I'd start out with the classic Todo List application.
The application simply loops forever asking the user to type a number to do specific actions, and will quit if the corresponding action (in this case, 4) is pressed.

There are comments that I think are parts of the code that need improvement, but if there is anything else then I'd be happy if you could point it out to me.

````rust
use std::io;
use std::process::Command;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    // NOTE 1) Should I specify the type, even when calling the `new` function on that type?
    let mut todo_list: TodoList = TodoList::new();
    faker_add_todos(&mut todo_list, 5);

    loop {
        clear_terminal();
        println!("What would you like to do?");
        println!("1. Add a new item.");
        println!("2. Display all items.");
        println!("3. Toggle item completion.");
        println!("4. Quit.");

        let choice = match read_user_input() {
            Ok(choice) => choice,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };
        let choice: u8 = parse_string_to_int(choice, 0);
        clear_terminal();

        match choice {
            1 => {
                println!("Enter the name of the to-do item:");
                // NOTE 2) This code is repeated a few times, should functions handle OK/Err or not?
                let name = match read_user_input() {
                    Ok(name) => name,
                    Err(_) => continue,
                };
                let notes: String = name.trim().to_owned();

                let item = TodoItem {
                    id: todo_list.auto_increment.increment(),
                    notes,
                    completed: false,
                };

                todo_list.items.push(item);
            },
            2 => {
                display_items(&todo_list.items);
                pause_terminal();
            },
            3 => {
                println!("Enter the ID of the task you want to complete.");

                // NOTE 3) What could cause std::io::read_line to Err?
                let id: String = match read_user_input() {
                    Ok(id) => id,
                    Err(_) => {
                        println!("Error reading data.");
                        pause_terminal();
                        continue;
                    },
                };

                let id: TodoId = match id.parse() {
                    Ok(id) => id,
                    Err(_) => {
                        println!("Please enter a valid ID number.");
                        pause_terminal();
                        continue;
                    },
                };

                // Locate the TodoItem that has the corresponding ID.
                match todo_list.items.iter_mut().find(|i| i.id == id) {
                    Some(item) => toggle_completed_item( item),
                    _ => {
                        println!("That ID could not be found. Please try again.");
                        pause_terminal();
                        continue;
                    },
                }
            },
            4 => {
                println!("Goodbye!");
                return;
            },
            _ => {
                println!("Invalid choice.");
                pause_terminal();
            },
        }
    }
}


/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Terminal functions
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Functions that handle interaction between the user and the Terminal, or the
| system and the Terminal are stored here.
|
*/

fn faker_add_todos(todo_list: &mut TodoList, count: u8) {
    for _ in 1..=count {
        todo_list.items.push(TodoItem {
            id: todo_list.auto_increment.increment(),
            notes: format!("Item {}", todo_list.auto_increment.value),
            completed: false,
        });
    }
}

// NOTE 4) Is it acceptable to handle errors within a function, or let the calling code handle the error?
fn parse_string_to_int<T: FromStr>(input: String, default: T) -> T {
    match input.trim().parse::<T>() {
        Ok(output) => output,
        Err(_) => default,
    }
}

// Forgive me for this horror!
fn clear_terminal() {
    print!("{}[2J", 27 as char);
}

// NOTE 5) What is the best way to pause a Terminal application.
fn pause_terminal() {
    let _ = Command::new("pause").status();
    let _ = Command::new("cmd.exe").arg("/c").arg("pause").status();
}

// NOTE 6) The compiler told me to write `let _` but I'm not sure what that means, it just gets rid of the error.
fn read_user_input() -> Result<String, String> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let _ = io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer);
    Ok(buffer.trim().to_owned())
}


/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Todo List functions
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| These are functions that
|
*/

fn toggle_completed_item(todo_item: &mut TodoItem) {
    todo_item.completed = match todo_item.completed {
        true => false,
        false => true,
    }
}

fn display_items(items: &Vec<TodoItem>) {
    for item in items {
        println!("{} - {} ({})", item.id, item.notes, item.completed);
    }
}


/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Definitions
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Any structs and implementations are to be defined here. This also includes
| type aliases.
|
*/

// NOTE 7) Is this a common practice for IDs?
//         Coming from a Laravel background, the ID field was always passed into
//         the database as ->id() rather than the data type under the hood.
type TodoId = u32;

struct TodoItem {
    id: TodoId,
    notes: String,
    completed: bool,
}

struct TodoListId {
    value: TodoId,
}

impl TodoListId {
    // NOTE 8) Is it good practice to specify the return type, if we are immediately returning that type?
    fn new() -> TodoListId {
        TodoListId {
            value: 0
        }
    }

    fn increment(&mut self) -> TodoId {
        self.value += 1;
        self.value
    }
}

struct TodoList {
    auto_increment: TodoListId,
    items: Vec<TodoItem>,
}

impl TodoList {
    fn new() -> TodoList {
        TodoList {
            auto_increment: TodoListId::new(),
            items: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NOTE 1) Should I specify the type, even when calling the `new` function on that type?
>
> ```
> let mut todo_list: TodoList = TodoList::new();
> ```

No, if the type is clear from the expression, `TodoList::new()`, don't repeat the type. In general, its pretty rare to explicitly label the type except when required because the type cannot be inferred.

> NOTE 2) This code is repeated a few times, should functions handle OK/Err or not?
>
> ```
>             let name = match read_user_input() {
>                 Ok(name) => name,
>                 Err(_) => continue,
>             };
> ```

It depends on the error. Can the function do something useful with the error? Can the calling function do something useful with the error? In this case,  I'd say there really isn't anything useful to do in an error condition. I'd suggest using the `color_eyre` or `anyhow` crate to define an error type and having `main` return a `color_eyre::Result<()>` or `anyhow::Result<()>` type. Then you can just use the `?` operator to terminate the program and print the error if it happens.

> NOTE 3) What could cause std::io::read_line to Err?
>
> ```
> let id: String = match read_user_input() {
> ```

Not much in practical situations. You could get an error if the standard input was closed or something like that.

> NOTE 4) Is it acceptable to handle errors within a function, or let the calling code handle the error?

It depends on the error, can you do something sensible? In this case, falling back to a default value if the text could not be parsed seem a bit strange. That's rarely a useful way to handle an error.

```
match input.trim().parse::<T>() {
    Ok(output) => output,
    Err(_) => default,
}
```

I'd do

```
input.trim().parse::<T>().unwrap_or(default)
```

I'd also probably not have a distinct function just for this.

```
// Forgive me for this horror!
fn clear_terminal() {
    print!("{}[2J", 27 as char);
}
```

You might be interested in the `crossterm` crate which gives you functions to manipulate the terminal in cross-platform manner.

> ```
> // NOTE 5) What is the best way to pause a Terminal application.
> fn pause_terminal() {
>     let _ = Command::new("pause").status();
>     let _ = Command::new("cmd.exe").arg("/c").arg("pause").status();
> }
> ```

Calling out to the pause command on windows work (on windows), but is a bit of a kludge. You could simply read a line and request the user push enter (instead of any key). If you want to wait for the user to push any key, you'll need to use something like `crossterm` to get lower level access to the terminal.

> ```
> // NOTE 7) Is this a common practice for IDs?
> //         Coming from a Laravel background, the ID field was always passed into
> //         the database as ->id() rather than the data type under the hood.
> type TodoId = u32;
> ```

I myself would use `struct TodoId(u32)` The distinction is that `TodoId` and `u32` would be different types. Then I can't accidently pass some other u32 as a `TodoId`

> ```
> // NOTE 8) Is it good practice to specify the return type, if we are immediately returning that type?
> fn new() -> TodoListId {
>     TodoListId {
>         value: 0
>     }
> }
> ```

You don't have a choice here. Rust won't infer the return type of a function.